# RectangleMapTool for defining polygon using mouse click does not work in QGIS 3.18

Tags: python, pyqgis, qgis-3, polygon-creation

I am using this code (below) to define a window where the user defines a polygon using the mouse click. In QGIS 3.16 everything works well, but I updated the QGIS to version 3.18 and now it does not work. Why?

After a while I see that the code that I have running (and that is not working) is different from the shared one. In this new code, the poinst are not connected to the main script.

This is the not working code:

```
class RectangleMapTool(QgsMapToolEmitPoint):
rect_created = pyqtSignal(QgsRectangle)
    def __init__(self, canvas):
        self.canvas = canvas
        QgsMapToolEmitPoint.__init__(self, self.canvas)
        self.rubberBand = QgsRubberBand(self.canvas, True)
        self.rubberBand.setColor(Qt.red)
        self.rubberBand.setWidth(1)

    self.points = []
    self.finished = False
    self.poly_bbox = False
    self.double_click_flag = False
    self.reset()

def reset(self):
    #self.startPoint = self.endPoint = None
    #self.isEmittingPoint = False
    self.rubberBand.reset(True)
    self.poly_bbox = False
    self.points.clear()

def keyPressEvent(self,e):
    #pressing escape resets the canvas. pressing enter connects the polygon
    if (e.key()==16777216):
        self.reset()
    if (e.key()==16777220):
        self.finishPolygon()

def canvasDoubleClickEvent(self,e):
    #finishes the polygon on double click
    self.double_click_flag = True
    self.finishPolygon()


def canvasReleaseEvent(self, e):
     
    if self.double_click_flag:
        self.double_click_flag = False
        return

  
    if self.finished:
        self.reset()
        self.finished = False

    self.click_point = self.toMapCoordinates(e.pos())

    self.rubberBand.addPoint(self.click_point, True)
    self.points.append(self.click_point)
    self.rubberBand.show()

def finishPolygon(self):

    if self.finished:
        return

   
    elif len(self.points)>2:
        first_point = self.points[0]
        self.points.append(first_point)
        self.rubberBand.closePoints()
        self.rubberBand.addPoint(first_point, True)
        self.finished = True
        # a polygon is created and added to the map for visual purposes
        map_polygon = QgsGeometry.fromPolygonXY([self.points])
        self.rubberBand.setToGeometry(map_polygon)
        # get the bounding box of this new polygon
        self.poly_bbox = self.rubberBand.asGeometry().boundingBox()
    else:
        self.finished = True

def getPoints(self):
    # Returns list of PointXY geometries, i.e. the polygon in list form
    self.rubberBand.reset(True)
    return self.points
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Is there an error?

Answer (score 5):

There are some simple indentation errors in your code. Mainly in the `rectangle()` method, your return statements were incorrectly indented.

After fixing the indentation errors your code worked for me in a recent build of the QGIS master branch on Ubuntu.

To show that show that a `QgsRectangle` object is being returned by the `rectangle()` method, I connected a slot to the `rect_created` signal which shows the created rectangle object in a `QMessageBox`.

I used this code:

```py
class RectangleMapTool(QgsMapToolEmitPoint):
    rect_created = pyqtSignal(QgsRectangle)
    def __init__(self, canvas):
        self.canvas = canvas
        QgsMapToolEmitPoint.__init__(self, self.canvas)
        self.msg = QMessageBox()
        self.rubberBand = QgsRubberBand(self.canvas, True)
        self.rubberBand.setColor(Qt.red)
        self.rubberBand.setWidth(1)
        self.reset()
        self.rect_created.connect(self.rectangle_created)
        
    def rectangle_created(self, r):
        self.msg.setText(str(r))
        self.msg.show()

    def reset(self):
        self.startPoint = self.endPoint = None
        self.isEmittingPoint = False
        self.rubberBand.reset(True)

    def canvasPressEvent(self, e):
        self.startPoint = self.toMapCoordinates(e.pos())
        self.endPoint = self.startPoint
        self.isEmittingPoint = True
        self.showRect(self.startPoint, self.endPoint)

    def canvasReleaseEvent(self, e):
        self.isEmittingPoint = False
        r = self.rectangle()
        if r is not None:
            self.rect_created.emit(r)
            # QMessageBox.about(self.dlg, "teste", str('ola'))
            # print("Rectangle:", r.xMinimum(),
            #     r.yMinimum(), r.xMaximum(), r.yMaximum()
            #    )

    def canvasMoveEvent(self, e):
        if not self.isEmittingPoint:
            return

        self.endPoint = self.toMapCoordinates(e.pos())
        self.showRect(self.startPoint, self.endPoint)

    def showRect(self, startPoint, endPoint):
        self.rubberBand.reset()
        if startPoint.x() == endPoint.x() or startPoint.y() == endPoint.y():
            return

        point1 = QgsPointXY(startPoint.x(), startPoint.y())
        point2 = QgsPointXY(startPoint.x(), endPoint.y())
        point3 = QgsPointXY(endPoint.x(), endPoint.y())
        point4 = QgsPointXY(endPoint.x(), startPoint.y())
        point5 = point1

        self.rubberBand.addPoint(point1, False)
        self.rubberBand.addPoint(point2, False)
        self.rubberBand.addPoint(point3, False)
        self.rubberBand.addPoint(point4, False)
        self.rubberBand.addPoint(point5, True)
        # true to update canvas
        self.rubberBand.show()

    def rectangle(self):
        if self.startPoint is None or self.endPoint is None:
            return None
        elif (self.startPoint.x() == self.endPoint.x() or \
              self.startPoint.y() == self.endPoint.y()):
            return None
        return QgsRectangle(self.startPoint, self.endPoint)

    def deactivate(self):
        self.rubberBand.reset()
        QgsMapTool.deactivate(self)
        self.deactivated.emit()
        
c = iface.mapCanvas()
t = RectangleMapTool(c)
c.setMapTool(t)
```

Result:

[image]